# QueueBackgroundWorkItem throwing ThreadAbortException

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api2, .net-4.5.2

I am trying to queue a background worker from inside a WebAPI call:

```
    public string TestThreadAbortException()
    {
        InitToolkit(DebugLevel.ERROR, 11937, true); // Initialize Logger, DB etc.
        var result = MyMethod(); // Runs through!
        DebugController.DoAfter(5.Seconds(), MyAction); // waits 5 seconds, and then calls MyMethod, waiting 20 seconds, but throws ThreadAbortException after 4 to 5 seconds into MyMethod
        return result;
    }

    private string MyMethod()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(20000);
        return "Test";
    }

    private void MyAction(Logger logger)
    {
        logger.Log(MyMethod());
    }


    public static void DoAfter(TimeSpan waitFor, Action<Logger> action)
    {
        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async ct =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(waitFor);
            DatabaseLogger logger = new DatabaseLogger();
            logger.Log("Executing " + action.Method.Name + ", " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            try
            {
                action(logger);
                logger.Log("Successfully executed " + action.Method.Name + ", " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.Log("Error in " + action.Method.Name + ": " + e.Message + ", " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            }
            finally
            {
                logger.CloseDatabase();
            }
        });
    }
```

This produces the following logs:

```
Executing MyAction, 10:30:51
Error in MyAction: Der Thread wurde abgebrochen., 10:30:55
```

But how do I find WHY the thread has been aborted, or how I can circumvent this issue? I understand that `Abort()` has been called on the thread, but I don't see why and where - there's no call to `Abort()` in my code!